# mysql how to filter data based on column values

Tags: mysql

I have a table, which contains four columns (a,b,c,d), in that one column (say c) contains always one of the  three varchar values  "Ok" or "SUCCESS" or "FAILED",

I need all the rows with all columns, that should be sorted by OK, then SUCCESS then FAILED.

Please Note: In my table "a" is an id (primary key).

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select * from `table` order by FIELD(c, 'OK', 'SUCCESS', 'FAILD')
```